# Multi select and delete anchor points on a vector shape - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, creative-cloud, pen-tool, anchor-point

[image]
Im trying to select multiple anchor points to delete on this shape. But when I go to delete the anchor points the shape turns to below? Any speculation on why this would be happening? If I delete each individual anchor point it seems to not have this problem but its just too time consuming to do that.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  How did you create this? How did you end up with all these stepped anchor points? TBH, it might be easier to just redraw the shapes with the pen tool.

Comment: I really can't see any anchor points here at all.. I see the blue highlight for paths, but I can't tell *where* any anchor points are and because of that.. it's somewhat impossible to state *why* deleting some changes the shape.

Comment: Okay. just a *guess*..... the white shapes are filled white... when you delete anchors, an *automatic* closing edge is created because there is a fill. Again, just guessing. I can't see the entire shape.. can't see anchors after you've deleted some...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting anchor points opens up your larger shape, which makes the fill go to the end points of the segments. Try to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> right after you delete those anchor points, or find some other way to close your shape.

It helps if you look at your shape in outline mode using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. This removes the formatting from the preview, no fills, no strokes, etc ... so you can check if your segments all connect into a single shape.

If your shape is broken into multiple segments, you will get this broken up fill.